# What can I do to improve this question on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

I've asked [Why UserControl isn't filling VerticalContentAlignment 'Stretch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620090/why-usercontrol-isnt-filling-verticalcontentalignment-stretch)

It seemed like I provided only what was appropriate:

- brief background, the goal
- code and Xaml to reproduce
- results

Reputation loss isn't the concern. I thought it was a well formed question. Although I received 2 upvotes (yay, a good question), I also received 3 downvotes. Not to mention that it was given a vote to close (Off Topic -> Why isn't this code working? ...).

What needs to be done to improve the quality of the question?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your question, especially since none if the voters explained their down vote. I'd prefer a small introduction before the first source code but I guess that's personal preference and has nothing to do with the question quality (since everything is given and explained at the end).

Comment: The close vote is for the "why isn't this code working".  I've noticed a very high intolerance for those types of questions that don't have exactly what the specific user is expecting to see in a very clear and concise manner.

Comment: @psubsee2003: okay, I suppose "why isn't this code working" is a *little* better. But still incorrect (IMHO) because I fulfill all the requirements for it to not be **that** kind of question. Thanks for the extra explanation.

Comment: Comments like *"Since when are we not having WPF questions allowed? Has there been some change on SO that I'm not aware of?"* attract downvotes.  The only thing I see is that this is a common question with the ItemsControl--content doesn't stretch horizontally/vertically as desired.

Comment: @Will: okay, completely rhetorical question - *since when does a comment modify the question?* ummm ... never. If the question is too commonly asked (which in my case I mentioned something I found specific and somewhat unique regarding the `ItemsControl`) then there is the option to mark as duplicate and provide a link to the existing question. Then this question on meta would never have existed.

Comment: You, for some reason, believe a person wouldn't downvote a question based on a comment the asker made beneath it.  I don't.  You seem to also not understand how downvoting works.  If you hover over the arrow, you will see that one of the reasons for downvoting is poor research. Downvoting someone for posting a dupe isn't unheard of.